# Insertar varias filas con un campo diferente y los demas iguales en php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy tratando de insertar varias filas en la misma consulta

Detalles:
Tengo varios campos en la tabla, y solo un campo tendría que ser diferente su valor en cada fila, los demás campos serian idénticos en cada fila.

Este es el código que tengo. pero parece que no voy por buen camino.

```
$insertar = mysqli_query ($link,"INSERT INTO temporal8 
            (articulo,fraccion,inciso,nombre,nombreDoc,ano,departamento,rango,nuevafecha,consecutivo,mes,destino,id) 
            VALUES ('$articulo', '$fraccion', '$inciso', '$nombre', '$nombreDoc', '$ano', ('ALUMBRADO','CATASTRO','COMPRAS'), '$rango', '$nuevafecha', '$consecutivo', '$mes', '$destino', NULL)") 
            or die("fallo al insertar los primeros datos: ".mysqli_error($link));
```

En el Campo `"departamento"` intento que inserte los diferentes valores.O sea que me genere 3 filas con valores repetidos a exepción del campo `"departamento"`

Comment: Tu lo que quieres es generar una fila para c/uno de los valores que deseas ingresar en "departamento"!? Es decir, generar 3 filas con todo igual excepto que el departamento.

Comment: Asi es @Rostan.. Eso es lo que necesito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Propondré un ejemplo en [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) , para que luego usted pueda adaptarlo a sus requerimientos.

Para el ejemplo propuesto tendremos una tabla con dos campos *nombre,edad* donde el valor fijo será el nombre y el valor que cambiará será la edad haciendo uso de un `for`*a modo de ejemplo* , Iniciamos creando la transacción con [beginTransaction](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.begintransaction.php) , [preparamos](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) la sentencia. Luego vinculamos los parámetros al valor que deseamos con [bindvalue](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) que adicional mente se le "debe" especificar el tipo de dato [mediante unas constantes](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.constants.php) que maneja `PDO` ,  para posteriormente en el `for` [ejecutamos](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php) la sentencia preparada.

*Ojo:* ejecutamos más no se realizan los cambios en la `BD` para que se realicen los cambios hay que emplear [commit](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.commit.php)

```
try { 
        /* Creamos La Conexión con PDO, modificar los valores respectivos*/
        $bd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mibd',"root", "",array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $bd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        /* Creamos la Transacción*/
        $bd->beginTransaction();
        /* Preparamos la Sentencia*/
        $sentencia = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO app (name,edad) VALUES (:name,:edad)");
        /* Le pasamos el valor fijo antes de entrar al For */
        $sentencia->bindValue(':name', 'MiValorFijo', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        for ($i=1; $i <5 ; $i++) { 
            $sentencia->bindValue(':edad', $i, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $sentencia->execute();
        }
         /* Aplicamos los Cambios en La BD */
        $bd->commit();
    }
catch (Exception $e) {
     /* Cancelamos La Transacción por si exista Error*/
    $mbd->rollBack();
    echo "Se Presento Un Error :  " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te recomiendo utilizar es 3 **VALUEs** separados por comas. Es decir:

```
$insertar = mysqli_query ($link,"INSERT INTO temporal8 
    (articulo,fraccion,inciso,nombre,nombreDoc,ano,departamento,rango,nuevafecha,consecutivo,mes,destino,id)
    VALUES ('$articulo', '$fraccion', '$inciso', '$nombre', '$nombreDoc', '$ano', 'ALUMBRADO', '$rango', '$nuevafecha', '$consecutivo', '$mes', '$destino', NULL),
        ('$articulo', '$fraccion', '$inciso', '$nombre', '$nombreDoc', '$ano', 'CATASTRO', '$rango', '$nuevafecha', '$consecutivo', '$mes', '$destino', NULL),
        ('$articulo', '$fraccion', '$inciso', '$nombre', '$nombreDoc', '$ano', 'COMPRAS', '$rango', '$nuevafecha', '$consecutivo', '$mes', '$destino', NULL)") 
or die("fallo al insertar los primeros datos: ".mysqli_error($link));
```

Con ello generas 3 inserciones a la base a la vez, y en cada uno cambias el valor de la columna. Saludos.