# Cómo puedo insertar varias filas a la vez en php usando PDO POO

Tags: php, poo, pdo

Necesito insertar *n* filas a la vez, como se muestra en la imágen:

Al hacer clic en el botón <kbd>+</kbd> se agregar otro ítem.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando PDO y estos son partes de mi código:

1. **cdp_detalle.php**:

   En el cual tengo la función `new()` que alimenta a la base de datos.

   ```
   function new ($dataQ) {
       $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO erp_cdp_det (tipo, codigo, descripcion, cantidad, cu, importe) VALUES $dataQ" ;
       if ($st = $this->conect->con->prepare($sqlQuery)) {
           $st->execute();
           return true;
           $this->conect->disconnect();
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

   **Al parecer mi error está en esta función.**
2. **cdp.php:**

   Este es el que obtiene los datos del formulario y se lo envía a la función `new()` del archivo 1.

   ```
   switch ($opcion) {
   case 'newDetalle':
       if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
           $items1     = ($_POST['tipo']);
           $items2 = ($_POST['codigo']);
           $items3     = ($_POST['descripcion']);
           $items4     = ($_POST['cantidad']);
           $items5     = ($_POST['cu']);
           $items6     = ($_POST['importe']);

           while (true) {
               $item1 = current($items1);
               $item2 = current($items2);
               $item3 = current($items3);
               $item4 = current($items4);
               $item5 = current($items5);
               $item6 = current($items6);

               $tipo  = (( $item1 !== false) ? $item1 : ", &nbsp;");
               $codigo  = (( $item2 !== false) ? $item2 : ", &nbsp;");
               $descripcion = (( $item3 !== false) ? $item3 : ", &nbsp;");
               $cantidad = (( $item4 !== false) ? $item4 : ", &nbsp;");
               $cu = (( $item5 !== false) ? $item5 : ", &nbsp;");
               $importe = (( $item6 !== false) ? $item6 : ", &nbsp;");

               $insertData = '("'.$tipo.'","'.$codigo.'","'.$descripcion.'","'.$um.'",'.$cantidad.','.$cu.','.$importe.','.$igv.','.$total.',"'.$cta_nat.'","'.$cta_dest.'",'.$erp_cdp_cab_id.'),';
               //Resta la ultima coma
               $dataQ = rtrim($insertData, ',');
               //envia los datos a la funcion new()
               $cdp_detalle->new($dataQ);

               $item1  = next($items1);
               $item2  = next($items2);
               $item3  = next($items3);
               $item4  = next($items4);
               $item5  = next($items5);
               $item6  = next($items6);

               if ($item1 === false && $item2 === false && $item3 === false && $item4 === false && $item5 === false && $item6 === false) break;
           }
       }

       break;}
   ```
3. **cdp.view.php:**

   Este es el formulario, en el cual cada input tiene en el atributo `name` un nombre como array, ejemplo: `name="name[]"`

*Por cierto, la conexión a la base de datos está correcta.*

Comment: Qué has intentado? Avanza con el código y compártelo con los problemas que te surgen.

Comment: No podremos ayudarle si no se tiene más contexto sobre su pregunta y además el código que intentó. podría ayudar mi respuesta a una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/80630/12864) relacionada

Comment: Por favor, tómate tu tiempo para aprender [ask] o pasarte por el [tour] del sitio. Ayudaría que aportaras un [mcve]. Bienvenido a SOes.

Comment: para hacer eso lo que necesitas es agregar filas de manera dinamica con Javascript-Jquery, eso en la parte de la vista, ya despues recibes los datos en forma de array y con un ciclo lo vas registrando en la base de datos

Comment: el problema es que no se me ocurre como guardarlo en array y mandarlo a la funcion new(), en cuanto a la vista todo bien, el boton + agregar con normalidad otro ítem.